# Subsetting data frame based on values a particular column takes

Tags: r, subset

Here is a trivialized example whose solution would help me greatly.

```
v.1<- c(5,8,7,2)
v.2<- c("hi", "hello", "hum", "bo")
df<- data.frame(v.1, v.2)
desired.values<- c("hi", "bo")
```

I would like all rows of the dataset where v.2 takes on one of the desired.values.

Desired output:

5   "hi"

2   "bo"

In my real dataset, v.2 has more than 10000 values and desired.values contains more than 2000 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df),v.2)[desired.values]
```

Or using `base R` methods

```
 df[df$v.2 %in% desired.values,]
```

Or

```
  df[grep(paste(desired.values, collapse="|"), df$v.2),]
```

Comment: may I know which package I need to download to use the function "setDT"? Even after downloading data.table, I get the error "Error in setkey(setDT(df), v.2) : could not find function "setDT"

Comment: @Zslice Have you loaded the library. ie. `library(data.table)`.  This should be very fast compared to the other methods

Comment: Yes, I have copied the first two lines of method 1 exactly (after installing the package)

Comment: @Zslice I am using data.table_1.9.5, but it should work in 1.9.4 as well.   When you load the package, do you get any errors?

Comment: This is the warning: "data.table 1.8.8  For help type: help("data.table")
Warning message:
package ‘data.table’ was built under R version 2.15.2 "

Comment: @Zslice I think you need to update your R Version.  The latest is `R 3.1.2`

Comment: I used the second method, which worked very quickly. Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: @Zlice No problem.  I would advise you to upgrade the R version as R 2.15.2 is a bit old.